# Is it possible to change the Route in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I've made search functionality that routes to `"/search/xxxx"` but it's in the header so when I search again, it repeats the route and makes `"/search/search/xxx"`.

Is there any way except `react-router` to solve this issue or could you give me advice?

```js
const searchHandler = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (router.asPath.startsWith("/search")) {
    history.back();
  }
  router.push("search/" + searchText);

  console.log(searchText); //sil

  setSearchText("");
  searchRef.current.blur();
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using an relative path which always append whatever you write as path value to the existing url, use absolute path. So `router.push("search/" + searchText);` will become `router.push("/search/" + searchText);`.

Here `search/` is relative and `/search/` is absolute. Make sure to add anything which comes before `/search/` as it will not get appended.

For example if your path is something like `http://localhost:3000/user/search/jhon` then the absoulute path will be `/user/search/jhon` and thus `router.push("/user/search/" + searchText);`.

Comment: I want the page to be reloaded when I routed there (actually i want nextjs to rerender the page) How to solve this could you know?